# How to add dynamic buttons using a string in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
List list=["A","B","C","D"];
```

I want to add each char on a separate raised button.
How can I generate only 4 raised button and add these values on that button. Like,

```
mButton1="A";
.
.
.
mButtonN="n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `map` operator

```
Column(
    children: myCharList.map((String char){
        return RaisedButton(child: Text(char)),
    }).toList(),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

**main.dart** full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Stack Overflow"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: list.map((String data) {
              return RaisedButton(
                child: Text(data),
                onPressed: () {
                  print(data);
                },
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: its showing me the error i.e. list cannot be assign to parameter type widget

Comment: hi @RahulSingh I have put full code of main.dart. Please try this. This may solve your problem.